ionic adding a box shadow to modal does not work
i am trying to get a shadow to the model popup to give it some dimension. but it does not apply. here is the code
 const modal = await this.modalCtl.create({
      component: ExplainNetworthComponent,
      cssClass: 'insight-explain-model',
      componentProps: {
        "insight": entry.explanation
      }
    })

    modal.present();

CSS
  .insight-explain-model {
    --max-height: 350px;
    --max-width: 80%;
    --box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    --backdrop-opacity: var(--ion-backdrop-opacity, 0.32);
  }


The code for modal looks likes below:
<ion-content class="ion-padding" style="--box-shadow: 5px 10px; --background: #E7F3ED">
    <ion-row>
     <ion-col>
       <ion-label class="ban-title2">Insight&nbsp;<ion-icon name="bulb-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-text-right" size="auto">
       <ion-button (click)="cancel()" fill="clear" size="small"><ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close-outline" size="small"></ion-icon></ion-button>
     </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
     <ion-col>
       <ion-label class="ban-sm-text">{{finData.explanation}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>


The --box-shadow property is not a standard CSS variable used directly in Ionic components like modals. Ionic components rely on the Shadow DOM or scoped styling which may not always allow global styles to apply as expected.
1. Target the Modal's Inner Element
Ionic modals use the .modal-wrapper class to style the modal content. You need to target the class inside your custom modal class.
Update your CSS like this:
.insight-explain-model .modal-wrapper {
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 8px; /* Optional: To make it look nicer */
 }

2. Verify Shadow DOM Isolation
If the component is using Shadow DOM, some styles might not apply directly. You can bypass this by using ::part pseudo-element or ::slotted selectors where supported.

didnt work this way

Please provide a sample running code in online platform so that I can check and assist further. Thanks.

added code for model. i am not using ion-model
